# shell find to not show root directory in search results

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a quick and prehaps easy to solve problem. 
I was listing a directories list via

`find ~/me/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "test1" -and -not -name "test4"`

```
$ find ~/me/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "test1" -and -not -name "test4"
/home/me/
/home/me/test2
/home/me/test3
```

I want to use something like: `find ~/me/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "test1" -and -not -name "test4" | xargs rm -rf`, however the find shows me the:
**/home/me root dir**.

I was looking for a way to not include it in the search results. Any hints?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `mindepth 1`? This way it will just depth=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-mindepth 1` not working for you?